# why JavaScript function returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

TwoSum, needs to return indices of the integers that add up to the target: Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9 Output: [0,1] Output: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].

I'm new to JavaScript and I dont understand why this returns undefined. After a few tests, i noticed it doesn't even enter the 2nd forloop, however when i wrote this in python it works perfectly

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] >= target) {
      continue;
    }
    for (let j = i; j < nums.legth; j++) {
      if (nums[j] >= target) {
        continue;
      }
      if (nums[i] + nums[j] === target) {
        const ans = [i, j]
        return ans;
      }
    }
  }
};
console.log(twoSum([2,7,11,15],9));
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you have negative values in the array?

Comment: Yes, you can have negative values in the array. But even for this case, it doesn't not enter the 2nd loop

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo mistake. Fix `legth` to `length` in second loop.

```js
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
      for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] >= target) {
          continue;
        }
        for (let j = i; j < nums.length; j++) {
          if (nums[j] >= target) {
            continue;
          }

          if (nums[i] + nums[j] === target) {
            const ans = [i, j];
            return ans;
          }
        }
      }
    };

    console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9));
```

Comment: @Noa Yesa Moshesa, can you accept this answer if it works?

Comment: for the input given [2, 7, 11, 15], 9 => the output should be [0,1] since you add 2 + 7 to get 9 and they are places in the 0 and 1 index

Answer (score -1):

I see this is an old question but still...

You have nested loops and that can be very confusing. One way I'd advise you to explore is to have your var ans defined in the function's main scope because you're not returning anything otherwise;

But I'd much rather advise you to use Array.reduce() as is current practice.
Here is my solution in [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/discuss/1605794/js-solution-with-arrayreduce):

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {

let acc = nums.reduce((acc, curr, currIndex, array) => {
    array.forEach((number, index) => {
        
        if(number + curr === target && index !== currIndex) {
            acc = [currIndex, index];
        }
    })
    
    return acc;
}, []);

return acc.sort();

};
```